# Ember.js + Handlebars custom helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to implement a simple conditional statement in Handlebars that changes based on an attribute in my controller.

I've managed to come up with;

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("businessVerificationState", function(state, block) {
  var value = Ember.getPath(this, "state");
  if (value == state) {
    return block(this);
  }
});
```

App.businessController.business refers to a model object I've created and "state" is an attribute. Below is the template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#with App.businessController.business}}
    {{#exampleState "test1"}}
      <p>Test 1</p>
    {{/exampleState}}

    {{#exampleState "test2"}}
      <p>Test 2</p>
    {{/exampleState}}
 </script>
```

This all works swell. Except when my model attributes changes. From the console in webkit .. if I type ..

business.set("state", "test2"); for example - nothing changes.

If I use other standard handlebar statements like IF or UNLESS - the content changes based on when I update model attributes.

Obviously I'm doing something incredibly wrong and would appreciate any help.

Comment: I believe you should be using `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have a parent view that has a property bound to the controller value and child views that have the state names specified as a property. You can then define an `isVisible` computed property which will automatically toggle visibility of the child view depending on if it matches the current value bound in the parent view.

Your template could look like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view Ember.View currentStateBinding="App.businessController.business.state"}}
    {{#view App.StateView stateName="test1"}}
      <p>Test 1</p>
    {{/view}}

    {{#view App.StateView stateName="test2"}}
      <p>Test 2</p>
    {{/view}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

And your JS code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.businessController = Ember.Object.create({
    business: Ember.Object.create({
        state: 'test1'
    })
});

App.StateView = Ember.View.extend({
    isVisible: function() {
        return this.get('stateName') === this.getPath('parentView.currentState');
    }.property('parentView.currentState')
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ebryn/QAxPU/